# How to make Crystal Report Database user independent?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report running over a DSN on a development environment.
The report refers stored proc DBSchemaA.StoredProc.

I have moved the report to run on crystal server which connects to a database where the Stored procro run is in DBSchemaB. I want the report to run DBSchemaB.StoredProc.

**Note**: Report has dynamic parameter which is filled by an list of values the stored proc returns which feed into a sub report.
When i change table prefix on Databse Configuration on server, it doesn't seem to affect the stored proc run for the list of values.
How do I achieve this without having to open the report in crystal on the development machine and connecting to the Database on server.
I do not have access to database on server from my development machine.
The database structure is exactly the same but is present under different schemas.

Comment: in short, i need to make report portable across environments without having to update it everytime I change environment. (Unless underlying data structure itself changes)

Comment: your requirement fulfill the CR, add in your comment that it also belong to only one DSN at any time, if you change anything at db level structure which refer to CR, you need to refresh CR

Comment: The DSN is same across all environments. its the database user owning the objects that changes across environments. Hope that makes sense.